# How to search js-data resources with Lunr on angular?

Tags: angularjs, jsdata, lunrjs

In my angular (1.3) app, I'm using [JSData](http://www.js-data.io/) (2.0.0), and I'd like to add full text search capabilities to those resources using [Lunr](http://lunrjs.com/), without Ajax. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a `SearchableDS` extension of JSData's `DS` resource for that purpose.

Here's a usage example:

```
angular.module("app")

.factory("User", function(SearchableDS) {
  var resource;
  // so far the same JSData code
  resource = SearchableDS.defineResource({
    name: 'user',
    endpoint: 'users',
    idAttribute: 'id',
    searchFields: { // Lunr searchable fields and their respective boost
      name: 7,
      title: 3
    }
  });
  return resource;
})
.controller(function(User) {
  // first we fetch all the records
  User.findAll({limit: 1000}).then(function() {
    var users;
    // now we can search local records
    return users = User.search('tim');
  });
});
```

`SearchableDS`:

```
angular.module("app")
.constant('Lunr', lunr) // lunr.js
.constant('_', _) // underscore.js
.service('SearchableDS', function(DS, Lunr, _) {
  _(this).extend(DS); // extending DS with new capabilites
  this.defineResource = function(options) {
    var addToIndex, defaultOpts, index, resource;
    defaultOpts = {
      searchMapper: angular.identity, // optional. a function to create objects for a different lunr mapping. useful for e.g. when the records have nested objects
      searchFields: {}
    };
    options = _(defaultOpts).extend(options);
    resource = DS.defineResource(options);
    index = Lunr(function() { // create lunr index
      var _this = this;
      this.ref(options.idAttribute); 
      // add searchable fields and their boost value to the index
      _(options.searchFields).each(function(boost, name) {
        _this.field(name, {boost: boost})
      });
    });
    addToIndex = function(entity) {
      index.add(options.searchMapper(entity));
    };
    // wrap the original record-fetching methods so that they'll add newly fetched records to Lunr's index
    resource.findAll = (function() { 
      var originalFunc;
      originalFunc = resource.findAll;
      return function() {
        return originalFunc.apply(resource, arguments).then(function(entities) {
          return _(entities).each(addToIndex); // add to lunr index
        });
      };
    })();
    resource.find = (function() {
      var originalFunc;
      originalFunc = resource.find;
      return function() {
        return originalFunc.apply(resource, arguments).then(function(entity) {
          return addToIndex(entity);  // add to lunr index
        });
      };
    })();
    // full text search of local records using Lunr
    resource.search = function(str) {
      var entities, ids;
      ids = _(index.search(str)).pluck('ref'); // use Lunr only to find the record IDs
      entities = _(resource.getAll())
      .chain()
      .filter(function(t) {
        return ~ids.indexOf(t.id)
      }).sortBy(function(t) {
        return ids.indexOf(t.id)
      })
      .value();
      console.log(options.name + "#search: " + entities.length + " results for '" + str + "'");
      return entities;
    };
    return resource;
  };
  return this;
})
```